# CFMail not sending to email address that has a single quote in it

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

How can I use cfmail to send an email to an address that has a single quote in it? For example:

> firstname.o'flanagan@example.com

For some reason I can't get an email sent to that address no matter what I do. Here's the cfmail tag code I'm using. I've tested all the variables and they're all defined:

```
<cfmail from="#getEmail.from_email#" 
        to="#email#" 
        subject="#getEmail.subject#" 
        type="HTML" 
        cc="#cc_email#" 
        bcc="#attributes.bcc_email#" 
        charset="UTF-8">
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you send to that address without using ColdFusion?

Comment: What actually happens when you try?

Comment: Is it a single quote, or is it one of the stupid things Microsoft Word converts single quotes to?

Comment: I just did a tag using firstname.o'flanagan@example.com as the to and from attribute without any problems on CF10. I didn't even use preservesinglequotes. I'd check your variable build up.

Comment: This could be conventions on your mail server as well. Try escaping with a backslash (that's the old convention I think - circa 1999). I would also tail the mail server log to see what it's telling you, and to see what it sees as the address (maybe it's mangling it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
<cfmail from="#getEmail.from_email#"
 to="#preserveSingleQuotes(email)#" 
 subject="#getEmail.subject#" type="HTML" 
  cc="#cc_email#" bcc="#attributes.bcc_email#" charset="UTF-8">
```

using the `PreserveSingleQuotes` should allow you to send to that address. Unfortunately using a single quote is valid in an email.

Comment: Yep i did and still got "The value of the attribute to, which is currently firstname.o'flanagan@example.com, is invalid."

Comment: if I try this : `
<cfscript>
 email = "firstname.o'flanagan@example.com";
</cfscript>
<cfmail from="test@example.com" to="#email#" subject="test" type="HTML" cc="" bcc="" charset="UTF-8">test</cfmail>` it woks as expected.

Comment: Damn, how could it work for you but not me? Same code. Server setting thing maybe?

Comment: Are you actually throwing a CF error or is the error in a log or an unsent email?